# How to calculate $\int_{0}^4\int_{y/2}^{2} e^{x^2} dxdy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

http://www4a.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP36251d183i6d402226cb000031ag27ead8g7fa5i?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=44&w=244.&h=42.

I can't make any strides in this problem so I typed it in on wolfram alpha to see if there is even a viable solution (apparently there is). The link above will give you a better picture of the problem. If anyone could help with this at all I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Wolfram gave an approximation, not an exact solution.

Comment: yes but I don't know how to do the exact approximation. That's why I went to wolfram in the first place. I don't care about what the answer is. I just want to be able to do the process.

Comment: "Exact approximation" is an oxymoron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap the integral terms:

$$\int_{0}^2 \int_{0}^{2x} e^{x^2}\,dy\,dx = \int_{0}^2 2xe^{x^2}\,dx$$

That latter integral you should be able to compute using a normal substitution.

The swap above is due to the fact that:

$$\left\{(x,y)\mid y\in[0,4], x\in[y/2,2]\right\}=\left\{(x,y)\mid x\in[0,2], y\in[0,2x]\right\}$$